# React Native Plate Scanning Not Working. My phone will read and scan the plate PROBLEM (There are no 64bit libs for Android.)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, opencv, openalpr

React Native plate not scanning. My problem is I can't get any errors. However it still doesn't work [sample site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-openalpr)

Library : OpenALPR and OPENCV

RESULT:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  As it stands your error is not reproducible at all and your question is at risk of being closed.

Comment: PROBLEM: There are no 64bit libs for Android.